# iOS UIScrollView clipToBounds = NO Subviews not detected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a scroll view that is 256x256 in width/height.  I have subviews of that scroll view stretching in both directions (left and right).  I set clipToBounds to NO so I can see the items in the scroll view.

When the user touches a space in the scrollview holder (the area that extends beyond the 256x256) I check the hittest and return the scrollView.

My problem is the items on my scrollview are buttons, and if the button is not inside the 256x256 it is not receiving the touch events. How do I cycle through the buttons on the scrollview and then forward the events to the buttons?

I'm doing like this [Paging UIScrollView with peeking neighbor pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735218/paging-uiscrollview-with-peeking-neighbor-pages)

But my scrollview subviews aren't receiving events.

I've tried all of the following in my view that is supposed to send events down the wire and my buttons will not receive the events. The event chain always stops at my UIScroll view - allowing me to scroll my items - but how do I forward events to the buttons from the scrollview?

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        return self.scrollView;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]) {
        return self.scrollView;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint) point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView* child = nil;

    if ((child = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event]) == self) {
        return self.scrollView;
    }
    return child;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This was the answer and better solution. Instead of having the arbitrary view to forward events, we just do this in the UIScrollView and all the buttons and swipes work fine.

```
- (UIView )hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent )event {
    UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if (view != nil && view.userInteractionEnabled) {
            break;
        }
        CGPoint newPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:subview];
        view = [subview hitTest:newPoint withEvent:event];
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing, and this worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you override the UIScrollView's hitTest?

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)pt withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{
    UIView *contentView = [self.subviews count] ? [self.subviews objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return [contentView hitTest:pt withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: I have this exact code in my scrollview custom class - but the buttons never receive the event.

Answer (score 0):

See the section *Detecting Touches Outside a Scroll View* in Matt Galloway's tutorial [How To Use UIScrollView to Scroll and Zoom Content](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) -

You make the scroll view smaller than the screen and with Clip Subviews unchecked:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

And wrap it into a container view, which forwards events to the scroll view:

```
- (UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (view == self) {
        return _scrollView;
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your scrollview should be bigger. 
All events outside the main scrollview's frame will not be detected. 
If you need to show the user a specific background zone, then put your scrollview's background transparent and put another view behind.

Comment: I made the scrollview the size it is because I need the paging to work properly. If I extend the scrollview width to the full width, then it pages the full width (instead of one icon). Is there a way to set the paging location programatically?